# Add id attribute to h1 element of wordpress post

Tags: posts, filters, title

The default rendering of the `h1` element of a wordpress post looks like this:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"> XYZ </h1>
```

I would like to add the `id` attribute to the `h1` element with the value of the post's title. The result should look as follows

```
<h1 id="XYZ" class="entry-title"> XYZ </h1>
```

I have already looked through many posts here, but couldn't find an answer to my question. Shouldn't there be a simple filter for `functions.php` to override the rendering of the `h1` element?

Comment: WordPress doesn’t render the h1 element. So there’s no hook. Your theme does. The h1 will be in your theme’s templates somewhere.

Comment: just found it. looked in the wrong place the whole time. should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the code editor. Be careful, do not write the head part, HTML tag and body tag. The syntax would be:

```html
<h1 id="XYZ">XYZ</h1>
```

Comment: Normally the h1 is provided by the theme though, not just the <html>, <head> and <body>. I think this needs a theme edit not anything in the admin site.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by adding a filter to modify the output of the post title in wordpress

When the filter is working mode then it checks if the current page is a single post `is_singular('post')`. If it is, it retrieves the post title, sanitizes it, and adds it as the id attribute to the `<h1>` element along with the existing title class. Then it returns the modified title

Add the following code to your themes `functions.php` file

```
function add_id_to_post_title_h1( $title, $id = null ) {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) { // Check if it's a single post
        $post = get_post($id);
        $title = '<h1 id="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $post->post_title ) ) . '" class="entry-title">' . $title . '</h1>';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_id_to_post_title_h1', 10, 2 );
```